# Fresco Image view in MaterialContainerTransform is not Showing

Tags: android, material-design, fresco

I have a Activity-A (RecyclerView) and Activity-B (ViewPager), On clicking on the item in the RecyclerView material transition to Activity-B with the item in ViewPager. on Landing on Activity-B Fresco image view isn't visible. Here the transition happens smooth but freso image view is not visible, If i swipe the pages in viewPager i could able to see the image

On Activity A

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        window.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS)
        setExitSharedElementCallback(MaterialContainerTransformSharedElementCallback())
        window.sharedElementsUseOverlay = false
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}
```

onClick

```
val intent = Intent(context, DetailActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra(DetailActivity.ARG_POSITION, position)
intent.putExtra(DetailActivity.ARG_TAB, viewModel.selectedTabItem)
val options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity,it,it.transitionName)
startActivity(intent, options.toBundle())
```

On Activity B

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  findViewById<View>(android.R.id.content).transitionName = "shared-container-$position"
  setEnterSharedElementCallback(MaterialContainerTransformSharedElementCallback())
  window.sharedElementEnterTransition = MaterialContainerTransform().apply {
      duration = 1000
  }
  window.sharedElementReturnTransition = MaterialContainerTransform().apply {
      duration = 1000
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with shared element transitions that don't properly set the visibility that Fresco uses to decide whether an image is on screen or not (for memory management purposes), see https://github.com/facebook/fresco/issues/1445

One fix here is to listen to the shared element end event and manually set the visibility of the image to visible, something like this:

```
ActivityCompat.setExitSharedElementCallback(this, new SharedElementCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSharedElementEnd(List<String> sharedElementNames, List<View> sharedElements, List<View> sharedElementSnapshots) {
                super.onSharedElementEnd(sharedElementNames, sharedElements, sharedElementSnapshots);
                if (FP.empty(sharedElements)) {
                    return;
                }
                for (View view : sharedElements) {
                    if (view instanceof SimpleDraweeView) {
                        ((SimpleDraweeView) view).getDrawable().setVisible(true, true);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```